# How does a slit modify a Gaussian X-ray beam?

Tags: waves, x-rays

It is well known that the X-ray beam coming from a tube X-ray source has a Gaussian distribution in divergence. If we put a slit of 100 microns symmetrically then will the beam coming from the slit be still a Gaussian immediately after the slit? If it still remains a Gaussian then what is the relation between the variance (sigma) and the slit width(100 micron in this case) immediately after the slit? How will the beam look after say 10 cm away from the slit?

Comment: Reference for this "well known"?